# Why a TCP WebRTC candidate with port 9 exists but the browser is not listening on this port?

Tags: webrtc

When I try to establish a connection using webRTC, I found always TCP candidate with port 9, however when I check the opened listening ports using "netstat -paunt" I didn't find that the browser is listening on the port 9.

I want to use juste TCP candidates , is there any way to make the browser listening on this port or get other TCP candidates without using a TURN server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Port 9 is the "discard" protocol, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discard_Protocol
In the context of ICE it means "there is no such port", see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6544#section-4.5 for details.

No browser supports listening on TCP ports. However, they support (and this is the reason you get those candidates, as a signal of support) connecting to a server via ICE-TCP as described in the [rtcweb transports draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-transports-17)